# Regex lookahead only removing the last character

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Im creating a regex that searches for a text, but only if there isnt a dash after the match. Im using lookahead for this:

- Regex: `Text[\s\.][0-9]*(?!-)`

`Expected result   Result
            ---------------   -------
Text 11     Text 11           Text 11
Text 52-    <No Match>        Text 5`

Test case: https://regex101.com/r/doklxc/1/

The lookahead only seems to be matching with the previous character, which leaves me with `Text 5`, while I need it to not return a match at all.

Im checking the https://www.regular-expressions.info/ guides and tried using groups, but I cant wrap my head around this one.

How can I make it so the lookbehind function affects the entire preceding match?

Im using the default .Net Text.RegularExpressions library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[0-9]*` backtracks and lets the regex engine find a match even if there is a `-`.

There are two ways: either use atomic groups or check for a digit in the lookahead:

```
Text[\s.][0-9]*(?![-\d])
```

Or

```
Text(?>[\s.][0-9]*)(?!-)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/CbxwrM/1/) and the [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/CbxwrM/2).

**Details**

- `Text[\s.][0-9]*(?![-\d])` matches `Text`,  then a dot or a whitespace, then 0 or more digits, and then it checks of there is a `-` or digit immediately to the right, and if there is, it fails the match. Even when trying to backtrack and match fewer digits than it grabbed before, the `\d` in the lookahead will fail those attempts
- `Text(?>[\s.][0-9]*)(?!-)` matches `Text`, then an atomic group starts where backtracking won't be let in after the group patterns find their matching text. `(?!-)` only checks for a `-` after the `[0-9]*` pattern tries to grab any digits.

Comment: Thanks! I think I ll use the atomic grouping case, it feels a bit more logic to me.

Comment: @Damntry Yes,  it makes more sense. If .NET regex supported possessive quantifiers, it would have been much cleaner: `Text[\s.][0-9]*+(?!-)`.