# Regext look ahead not working as expected (As I learned about it)

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have formula with variables and constants such as numbers.
From that formula I want to grep only variables, not functions
https://regex101.com/r/bPLoAP/2

Something similar I found here

[Regex for string not ending with given suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix)

My regex expression is: `([A-zА-я]+[0-9]*(?!\())`

With this regex expression I expect to see variables not ones that have beginning parenthesis "("

But what I see is that regex is throwing last symbol from word which has starting parenthesis after it

Comment: Try `'/(?>[a-zа-яё]+[0-9]*)(?!\()/ui'`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, answer, and I will mark it a resolved

Comment: You may upvote my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835788/3832970) that shows the usage of the atomic grouping.